# How to set transparent as Text color for a Text in React Native

Tags: react-native

Will it be possible to set the color of `Text` to transparent and let the text alone inherit the parent views background color, not it's own background color!

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
  <Text style={{ color: 'transparent',  backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
    Change text colour progressively
  </Text>
</View>
```

**CURRENT BEHAVIOR**

Since the text color is transparent, it inherits it's own background color(blue), so no text will be visible.

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR**

The text alone need to inherit the parent view's background colour(red).

My final goal by this is to implement an animation, where the text colour can be changed progressively. I am not sure of the behaviour in web or any, just curious if there is any possibility of achieving this.

## Targeting Animation:

[image]

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing the following code:

```js
<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
<View style={{ color: 'transparent' }}>
  <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}> Change text colour progressively </Text>
</View>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried and this is the output.

Comment: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vq2f7a3sa7vvom/Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20-%20iPhone%205s%20-%202018-03-31%20at%2011.11.09.png?dl=0]

Answer (score -1):

```
render() {
    const bgColor = 'red'; // try updating this color
    return(
       <View style={{backgroundColor: bgColor, padding: 15}}>
           <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', padding: 10}}>
                <Text style={{color: bgColor, fontSize: 18}}>
                    Change text color progressively
                </Text>
           </View>
       </View>
    );
}
```

Code in live action =>
https://snack.expo.io/HyZapc3qG

Comment: Would not this change the whole text(Change text color progressively) colour straight away?
I am trying to achieve an effect similar to this
[https://www.dropbox.com/s/skq6lj49vzp6hpd/image%20%281%29.png?dl=0]

Comment: For this the text colour need to be transparent and text alone should show the parent view's background colour. Then I can translate the X value of parent view positioning Text 'absolute' and can have an effect like gradual change of text colour.